# How to use facades and libs directly from views

Tags: php, laravel

I have my Laravel app setup in a pretty standard way and a bunch of external libs installed via Composer.

Laravel does all the boostrapping by pulling the `.env` variables and establishing database connections. At the top of each controller I have, for example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Users;

use GuzzleHttp;
use MongoClient;

class UsersController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to require existing facades and DB connections in my views. I do realize that this is a bad practice but I would really like to understand how to use for example `MongoClient` directly from within the view.

Thanks!

Comment: if it is a facade:`MongoClient::someMethod(...)` ... it is in the root namespace, just use it ... if you need an instance of something there is the `@inject` blade directive to inject an instance of something

Answer (score 0):

since Laravel use the MVC (Model Vue Controller) pattern, i can confirm that it's really a bad practice and i really don't recomand to do it.

what do you want to acheive can be seen as a dependency injection (But it's really not)

there is 2 ways to proceed :

1. plain php behave : you declare a php block in the top of your file.blade.php

and there further in the your file.blade.php you make for example

```
<?php
   MongoClient::someMethod(...)
?>
```

2. second way you inject it as a dependency injection with the attribute

   @inject('mongoExampleName', 'App\Services\MongoService')

But then you have to create a service container for it and bind it with the service provider.

In the end i really dont recomand this, it was just to show the possibilities.

Good luck